# Visual Studio debugger starts Chrome with text darkened

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, visual-studio-2019, dark-mode

Whenever I start debugging a web project from Visual Studio 2019, and it opens Google Chrome, various text in Chrome darkens. The tab title, the forward/back arrows, and the folder names in the bookmarks bar all darken.

[Screen capture of darkened text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7eQl.png)

On subsequent openings of Google Chrome, the text remains dark, and it has even gotten to the point where Google syncs the darkened text to other computers with that Google Account.

As a workaround, I've been enabling Windows 10's high contrast settings, and then disabling them to "reset" all of the font styles in Google Chrome. This works until I start debugging from Visual Studio again.

Another workaround that works is removing and re-adding the Google Theme. I've used multiple different themes, it isn't just the one I'm using ("Just Black").

Is there a setting in either Windows or Visual Studio to prevent this from happening?

Comment: My best guess is that Visual Studio is leveraging something from Windows to darken the text in the Visual Studio menus, and, as a side effect, is also darkening Google Chrome's text.

Comment: Are you using a Dark theme in Windows?

Comment: I am not using a Dark theme in Windows

Comment: Does this happen if you are **not** using the Google Theme before starting Visual Studio?

Comment: The default Chrome browser has dark text similar to what is experienced after starting Visual Studio. It's impossible to tell. I can say that I've tried a variety of themes, and if that theme's text is of a different color, it changes back to that dark text after starting Visual Studio. It isn't just this one theme.

Comment: I meant what happens when not using any theme except the default one.

Comment: It doesn't change. The default theme's text color is the same as what the problem produces though.

Comment: I found an answer for myself. what I'm fascinated by is how this problem has caused my other computers to sync this dark text as if it's a feature. devices that don't have visual studio at all. Visual Studio was replicating the problem every time for me though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating Visual Studio 2019 to its newest version (without upgrading to 2022), the problem resolved itself.

I went from 16.10.4 to 16.11.10

Edit:
Seems like this was fixed in version [16.11.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#top-issues-fixed-in-this-release):

> Fixed an accessibility issue causing High Contrast Account Settings to not show.

or

> Fixed the Luminosity contrast ratio for Country boundary Foreground/background color to be greater or equals to 3:1 so that visually impaired users can identify these controls.